# Storing enumerate in a macro breaks \endenumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate

I need to alter the `enumerate` environment so that I can store some data that I want to print later also in `enumerate` (at corresponding levels). However, when I do this, `\end{enumerate}` seems to be broken and the levels only increase.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\SavedEnum{}

\let\BeginEnumerate\enumerate
\def\enumerate{%
    \g@addto@macro\SavedEnum{\BeginEnumerate}%
    \BeginEnumerate}

\let\EndEnumerate\endenumerate
\def\endenumerate{%
    \g@addto@macro\SavedEnum{\EndEnumerate}%
    \EndEnumerate%
}

\let\OldItem\item
\def\item<#1>{%
    \g@addto@macro\SavedEnum{\OldItem#1}%
    \OldItem%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item<1st level> level 1
    \item<> \begin{enumerate}
        \item<2nd level> level 2
    \end{enumerate}
    \item<> \begin{enumerate}
        \item<2nd level> level 2
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

---

\SavedEnum
\end{document}
```

**Result of the code above:**
[image: Result of the code above]

**Desired behavior:**
[image: Desired behavior]

Comment: This idea is quite smart!

Comment: I update my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The depth of the enumeration is confused by this proceeding, unless there's grouping:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter

\def\SavedEnum{}

\let\BeginEnumerate\enumerate
\def\enumerate{%
    \g@addto@macro\SavedEnum{\begingroup\BeginEnumerate}%
    \BeginEnumerate }

\let\EndEnumerate\endenumerate
\def\endenumerate{%
    \g@addto@macro\SavedEnum{\EndEnumerate\endgroup}%
    \EndEnumerate%
}

\LetLtxMacro\OldItem\item
\def\item<#1>{%
  \g@addto@macro\SavedEnum{\OldItem#1}%
  \OldItem%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item<1st level repeat> level 1 1st orig
\item<> 
  \begin{enumerate}  
  \item<2nd level repeat> level 2 2nd orig
  \end{enumerate}
\item<>
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item<2nd level repeat> level 2 -- 3rd orig
     \item<another level repeat> another level
 \begin{enumerate}
   \item<3rd level repeated> level 3
     \end{enumerate}

  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

---

\SavedEnum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like magic, thanks! However, I still don't understand too well why the grouping is necessary inside the saved part but not in the direct part.

Comment: @PavelSikora: I'll could track it down an interference with the `\@listdepth` counter (used by the `\list` command in the `enumerate` definition (`latex.ltx`) and the `\@enumdepth`. However, I don't understand at the moment, why this happens at all

Answer (score 2):

your  `\SavedEnum` is equivalent to

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\enumerate
\item 1st level 
\item
\enumerate \item 2nd level\endenumerate
\item
\enumerate \item 2nd level\endenumerate
\endenumerate
\end{document}
```

when using commands first `\endenumerate` will end first `\enumerate`.

**Update** Now try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
    \item level 1
    \item \begin{enumerate}
        \item level 2
    \end{enumerate}
    \item\begin{enumerate}
        \item level 2
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}



\begingroup\enumerate
\item 1st level 
\item
\begingroup\enumerate \item 2nd level\endenumerate\endgroup
\item
\begingroup\enumerate \item 2nd level\endenumerate\endgroup
\endenumerate\endgroup
\end{document}
```

**why the grouping is necessary inside the saved part but not in the direct part?**

In the direct part grouping are add by `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}`

In fact `\begin{...}` is equivalent to something like `\begingroup \...` and `\end{...}` is equivalent to something like `\end...\endgroup`

Here

```
\begin{enumerate}=\begingroup\enumerate=\begingroup addtomacro...\BeginEnumerate=\begingroup addtomacro...\enumerate
```

and

```
\end{enumerate}=\endenumerate\endgroup=\addtomacro...\EndEnumerate\endgroup=\addtomacro...\endenumerate\endgroup
```

**Solution**

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\SavedEnum{}

\let\BeginEnumerate\enumerate
\let\EndEnumerate\endenumerate
\newenvironment{Enumerate}{\BeginEnumerate}{\EndEnumerate}

\def\enumerate{%
    \g@addto@macro\SavedEnum{\begin{Enumerate}}%
    \BeginEnumerate}


\def\endenumerate{%
    \g@addto@macro\SavedEnum{\end{Enumerate}}%
    \EndEnumerate%
}

\let\OldItem\item
\def\item<#1>{%
    \g@addto@macro\SavedEnum{\OldItem#1}%
    \OldItem%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item<1st level> level 1
    \item<> \begin{enumerate}
        \item<2nd level> level 2
    \end{enumerate}
    \item<> \begin{enumerate}
        \item<2nd level> level 2
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

---

\SavedEnum
\end{document}
```